# Duplicate TreeView control with only checked nodes using Web.UI.WebControls TreeView

Tags: c#, treeview

I am using the Web version of the TreeView control in C# and I have one TreeView with checkboxes on a page.  The user will select 1:n of the leaf nodes in the TreeView.  Parent nodes are only selectable so that the user can select all children without clicking every single one.  Once the user has checked the desired nodes they will click a button and will be brought to a new page.  For this page, I would like to be able to pass a TreeView object with the same heirarchy as the previous page's TreeView, but only displaying nodes that are checked or the parents of nodes that are checked.  I've seen a lot of examples using the Web.Forms version of TreeView, but I can't seem to find a good way to do it using the Web.UI version.